# Integer grid points intersection with sphere

Tags: geometry, spheres

I'm wondering how many intersections does a centered sphere with radius $r$ ($r$ is an integer) have with an integer grid? For sure the 6 intersections with the axises, e.g. $(x,y,z)=(r,0,0)$. Actually, it should be enough to know how many intersections there are in the first quadrant, since the problem is symmetric.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is the set of **Waterman polyhedra**. Those are defined by the convex hull of the intersection of some lattice (you are interested in the simple cubic one) and a ball of increasing radius, centered at some lattice point.

For further info cf. to the corresponding **wiki page**: [Waterman polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterman_polyhedron)
or esp. the relevant one on the **website of Steve Waterman** directly: [simple cubic](http://watermanpolyhedron.com/MENSscZZZ.html)

--- rk